# What is the RMS value of this waveform

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, math, rms

I would like to know what is the RMS value of this waveform. I would like to see the mathematics. I ve done the mathematics but it seems that the result has a lot of terms ... If some approximations are made, please tell me in which conditions these approximations can be done.

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you have a specific EE question rather than a math question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your waveform is poorly labeled.

See this example

[image]

And we have:

$$I_{AV} = \frac{I_{max}+ I_{min}}{2}$$

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{I_{AV}^2 +\frac{(I_{max}-I_{min})^2}{12}} \approx I_{AV}$$

Now you can try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Are you sure of the RMS result ? This is not an approximation ? It does not depend on the duty cycle ? I will try tomorrow again to find your answer !

Comment: I think it would help Jess if you explain where exactly you got that RMS equation :)

Comment: This is the correct formula. I found it via the calcul

Answer (score 2):

For the case of a periodic signal with period \$T_p\$ you can use a different formula for the rms, and not worry about the integration limits going to infinity.

$$f_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T_p}\int_0^{T_p} f^2(t) dt}$$

With this definition, you should be able to simply calculate the RMS value of your periodic signal directly from the formula.